# Why did Rabbi Shila hide what he said?

Tags: talmud-gemara, tractate-brachot

In [Berakhot 58a](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.58a.14?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he), Rabbi Shila thanks G-d by saying:

> ״לְךָ ה׳ הַגְּדֻלָּה וְהַגְּבוּרָה וְגוֹ׳״

When he's asked by the authorities about what he said, he replies:

> ״בְּרִיךְ רַחֲמָנָא דְּיָהֵיב מַלְכוּתָא בְּאַרְעָא כְּעֵין מַלְכוּתָא דִרְקִיעָא, וִיהַב לְכוּ שׁוּלְטָנָא וְרָחֲמִי דִּינָא״

Why did Rabbi Shila respond with something completely different (or rather, something more refined) to what he actually said?

Comment: It doesn't look to me like he said something wildly different the second time, he was just explaining the verse that he said. I'm understanding the question of "What did you say" as "Can you explain what you said", not "I didn't hear you, please repeat it". It's like if you say a Brachah on food out loud, and a stranger asks you "What did you say", you wouldn't repeat the Brachah verbatim, you would say something like "I made a blessing thanking G-d for the bounties of this world".

Comment: Second @Salmononius2. Also, seems to me the king didn't know Hebrew. Rav Sheilah simply translated and expounded a little.

Comment: @Salmononius2, I agree with Harel13 that the authorities may not have known Hebrew, hence his translation. However, it seems to me that he was flattering the authorities, rather than explaining